# Java\Android timestamp returns wrong hour value

Tags: java, android, timestamp

For some reason I get 2 hours in the clock while I've only been running it for few seconds.
Here are the results of the time stamps and the code:

```
08-12 01:03:47.858: I/System.out(2856): 1344722627872
08-12 01:03:51.198: I/System.out(2856): 1344722631206
08-12 01:03:54.698: I/System.out(2856): 3334
08-12 01:03:54.758: I/System.out(2856): 02:00:03




public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)  {

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
     return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());   }
```

This is the complete code with the calling:

```
// Click Listener for Check In\Out Button

    checkIn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Check Out
            myVib.vibrate(10);
            if (clicked == true) {
                timeStampWhenOut = System.currentTimeMillis();
                killcheck = true;
                checkedStatus = "Check In";
                checkIn.setText(checkedStatus);
                long getShiftLength = ShiftLength(timeStampWhenIn,
                        timeStampWhenOut);
                System.out.println(timeStampWhenOut);
                System.out.println(getShiftLength);
                System.out.println(getDate(getShiftLength, "hh:mm:ss"));
                clicked = false;
                wasShift = true;

                // Check In
            } else if (clicked == false) {

                timeStampWhenIn = System.currentTimeMillis();
                System.out.println(timeStampWhenIn);
                checkedStatus = "Check Out";
                checkIn.setText(checkedStatus);
                killcheck = false;
                clicked = true;

            }
        }
    });
```

Why are the hours wrong?

Comment: Wait a second, are you passing in an elapsed time?  You can't do that - Calendar.setTimeInMillis expects a time since the epoch.

Comment: In 2017, look into `java.time.Duration`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `3334` is an elapsed time, you're setting the Calendar to 3.334 seconds since the epoch (approximately midnight GMT on December 31st 1970).  Then you're formatting that Calendar.  And it's telling you that it's 2am plus 3 seconds in your time zone, by which I guess that your time zone is GMT+2.

Don't use Calendar and SimpleDateFormatter for elapsed times - it's not the right tool for the job.  Have a look at DurationFormatUtils in Apache-Commons instead.

Comment: Then what would be the best way for me to get this info? I need to know how long it has been since the user "clicked in" and until he clicked out"

Comment: @Yosi199: You're trying to format a *duration* (how many milliseconds has elapsed) - but that's not a *date and time*. It's reasonable to format` timeStampOut` and `timeStampIn` as date/time values (although I'd suggest HH instead of hh) but you shouldn't try to format `getShiftLength` that way.

Comment: Thank you guys I now understand better why it is wrong. Would you mind giving me an example of what is the RIGHT way to do it?

Comment: @Yosi199, have a look at Android DateUtils.formatElapsedTime http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine for me. Could you show where you call the getDate method? Here's how im using it:

```
System.out.println(getDate(System.currentTimeMillis(), "hh:mm:ss"));
```

And that's logging the right time (current for me 6:10:29)

EDIT:
Why are you even using the calendar in the middle? You hand your method milliseconds, which it puts in a calendar, then takes right back out.

```
public static String getDate(long milliSeconds, String dateFormat)  {

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

     return formatter.format(milliSeconds);
}
```

^ That would be much better

Comment: The last line in my I\O output is a calling of this method.
You can see it's only running for a few seconds (according to the timestamps), but it prints as if it's passed 2 hours.

Comment: I think it must have to do with GMT time cause I'm in GMT+3 and I've played some with GMT settings and the hours value was changed. But I dont know how to fix this in my code

Comment: Calendar.getInstance() should return the calendar in the same timezone as your system. Could you just show the code where you call it though?